# Let M be a set and let d be a function from $M \times M$ into $\mathbb R$ . Prove that $d: M \times M -- [0, \infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a set and let d be a function from $M \times M$ into $\mathbb R$ which satisfies the properties:

1. $d(x,y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y$
2. $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$ for all $x,y \in M$
3. $d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ for all $x,y,z \in M$

Prove that $d: M \times M \to [0, \infty)$.

Comment: I presume that property (3) is some variety of the triangle inequality, but you posted the question without completing the statement of property (3). Please clarify.

Comment: The (3) property is the triangle inequality. My apologies. I am new to the site so still working out formatting issues. The question is complete now.

Comment: Hint: for an arbitrary pair $x,y\in M$, see what you can yield from looking at $d(x,x)$ or $d(y,y)$.

Comment: So you have axioms of metric but you have omitted the condition that it is non-negative. And you are trying to show that non-negativity follows from other conditions? You should probably clarify in the question whether this is what you are after. If yes, this can be found in the [Wikipedia article on metric spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) (link to the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Metric_space&oldid=712719666#Definition).) See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1537657).

Comment: You may also be interested in my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2000056/113214) which shows that you can actually reduce the required properties to only two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $z=x$ to obtain $$0 = d(x,x) \leq  d(x,y) + d(y,x) = 2d(x,y)$$ so that $d(x,y)\geq 0$ as required.

The first "$=$" is from property 1, the "$\leq$" is from property 3, and the second "$=$" is from property 2.

Answer (score 1):

Proceed by contradiction:

suppose there exists a pair $(x, y) \in M \times M$ such that $d(x, y) < 0$, use symmetry and triangle rule with $z = x$ and see what happens!

Comment: There's no need for that. It is a direct consequence of the other properties (see my answer).

Comment: haha I love the little (see my answer) at the end.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. But +1 for your correct answer nonetheless.